# Ignoring hostname verification in Android SSL Sockets without HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

*How do I turn off hostname verification if I can't use the HttpsUrlConnection class?*

In debug mode (and ***only*** in debug mode) I find it convenient to ignore hostname verification, because each team member has virtual servers and debugging against them is a pain in the neck if they need signed certificates.

With `HttpsUrlConnection` this is easy to achieve (`setHostnameVerifier`).

However, I'm not using `HttpsUrlConnection` today - I'm using something else related to `SSLSocket` objects because I want a web socket client and `HttpsUrlConnections` don't support web sockets.  The connections are failing because the certificate cannot be verified (good for them - that is correct behaviour) but I want to make them carry on regardless.

They die with

```
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:409)`
```

I've set up the `SSLContext` with my own trust manager so that all certificates are accepted, but I can't find a way to switch of the hostname test.

Comment: basically u need host name dynamically?

Comment: I suppose so - it doesn't change rapidly, but I might get a new name tomorrow and I don't feel like signing a new certificate every day

Comment: there is only options seems to me : 1. either use checkbox which can be used to testing purpose and use `http` connection OR 2. sign multiple cert and keep on server or device and use `https` connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier does not have an equivalent for raw SSL sockets and isn't required - you can simply ignore that bit.  I was basically trying to preempt a problem that doesn't exist and it threw me off - so long as you set your own TrustManager up for the SSLContext you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

> I find it convenient to ignore hostname verification, because each team member has virtual servers and debugging against them is a pain in the neck if they need signed certificates.

You mixup hostname verification and certificate signing. The validation of the server with HTTPS is done by

1. Verifying the trust chain, that is if the certificate is signed by a trusted root-CA (and maybe some chain certificates in between).
2. Checking that the subject of the certificate matches the expected hostname from the URL.

You are trying to disable #2 only. If you are really in a test setup and want to use self-signed certificates you need to also disable #1. If you instead import the self-signed certificates as trusted you could also issue the certificates so that they match the expected hostname.

Comment: OK, thank you for clarifying that. I would cheerfully disable both, but my question still stands because I don't know how to go about doing so.